# Is it recommended to put a custom Windows install or keep the brand's one?

Tags: windows-10, iso-image

Heelo everyone,

I've read some thread about that, but I'm still not get a real answer.
I just got an Acer with an I7 8xxx, and a good SSD. The PC is quick, but if it can be better, that better! I'm making customs windows 10 iso with WinToolsKit to light it up, and remove all the unnecessary package to run on low config PC. I hesitate to make one for this PC, but I don't know if I can get issues with hardware like the battery or just a bad windows build. I'm using it for study and programming.

For you, with your experience, do you recommend me to put a custom W10 iso on it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. You may want to remove/modify your last paragraph because it could get the post closed as it changes the post from fact based (OK) to opinion based (off topic). You may want to consider putting your second paragraph as a seperate question.

Comment: Thanks, it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is up to you whatever you wish to do. Name brand manufacturers mostly now limit their offerings to update and support routines plus diagnostic apps.

None of these burden the computer but are great to have when problems arise.

Further, with Windows 10, most manufacturers have an app that can create a bootable USB key. That can be a life saver.

Finally, if you roll your own Windows, you have to also roll your own driver package as Video, Audio, Wireless and Power Management (and more smaller drivers) because you need these.

We use the Vendor's build for our clients, hide anything not needed and install software that we need. We do this correctly and have very few issues.

ALL Windows (net of drivers certified for the manufacturer) are the same. Vendors do not rewrite Windows. To rewrite Windows make no business sense.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. I'm gonna look to what you mentionned "Vendor", and just run a W10-debloat to remove the useless things.

Comment: Thank you. I think that is the correct path.